# Is there a cross OS (win/mac) scripting languagee?

Tags: operating-systems, shell-script, cross-platform

I use Autohotkey for all my Windows scripting, but would like to use something that could apply to a Mac as well.  Without having to write it in multiple languages.  And having it compatible with Linux wouldn't hurt either.  Is there such a thing?  I'd want to use it for file manipulation, OS operations specifically, and hotkeys/mouse gestures would be nice as well.

If not, wouldn't it be possible to create a single language, then have a separate Windows and Mac interpreter that would implement the command according the the OS running it?  Then use conditional statements in which there aren't equivalent features/funtions on each OS?

If the above doesn't exist, is there something close, or two languages similar in syntax making it easy to implement on both platforms?

Thanks!

** Found tons of answers soon after posting this.  Stack Exchange had more than enough info when searching for cross OS scripting **

Answer (score 1):

Haha, googled the wrong keywords I guess.

Python (with the right modules) can support hotkeys, take screenshots, and plenty more.  That'll probably be what I go with.

I won't list everything here, but if anyone else is curious, Stack Exchange has plenty of Q&A on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

- Bash/Shell if you install UnixTools or Cygwin will then run on Mac/Windows/Linux.
- Python, Ruby
- Beanshell (http://www.beanshell.org/) is also a good choice. There are some Robot class in Java you can use for GUI interaction and many other 3rd party packages.

As for *"If not, wouldn't it be possible to create a single language, then have a separate Windows and Mac interpreter that would implement the command according the the OS running it?"*

Well that's what a scripting language is. The above answers are example of what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

Perl is installed by default on just about everything but Windows. In the *nix world, it is probably still the most widely used non-shell language for all sysadmin tasks.

Answer (score 0):

dozens, like java and python, as a bare start.

Comment: Java is not a scripting language.

Comment: true, but it's still something to consider, i was probably tired, was thinking perl, i dunno, basic, f no, povray, not in this situation.